# Signed AWS Cloudfront URLs for the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app using Cloudfront as my CDN.  And I wanted to add a layer of I just turned on the signed URL feature and all my asset pipeline links now fail.

My AWS uploaded files, images etc. still all work as they are being displayed with the proper signed URLs because they use Carrierwave to generate the URLs.

I ended up manually updating my stylesheet and javascript urls to signed but now I realize that all my CSS links in my CSS (Fontawsome gems etc.) and the odd local static images I have all fail because they too need to be signed.

Is there not a way to do this globally for the asset pipeline in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but I didn't want to leave this question hanging.  I ended up moving to Signed Cookies.  This way I can restrict access to signed in users.  I figured this may help someone with the same issue.